# Recursive Folder creation

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

Im sitting with a brain teaser that I cannot seem to complete. I am trying to create a specific folder structure. The structure is explained here:

In the root folder specified, the application should create 10 folders, '0' - '10'. Inside each of these, should again be folders '0' - '10', and etc. This must go on to a user defined level.

Using for loops, I have managed to get this so far, but can imagine that a recursive function will look a lot less messy, but melts my brain at the same time trying to figure it out D:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            string basePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Lib");

            for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
            {
                CreateFolders(basePath);
                basePath = Path.Combine(basePath, a.ToString());

                for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
                {
                    CreateFolders(basePath);
                    basePath = Path.Combine(basePath, b.ToString());

                    for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
                    {
                        CreateFolders(basePath);
                        basePath = Path.Combine(basePath, c.ToString());

                        for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++)
                        {
                            CreateFolders(basePath);
                            basePath = Path.Combine(basePath, d.ToString());

                            basePath = Helpers.DirMoveBack(basePath);
                        }
                        basePath = Helpers.DirMoveBack(basePath);
                    }
                    basePath = Helpers.DirMoveBack(basePath);
                }
                basePath = Helpers.DirMoveBack(basePath);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
       }

// Creates folders '0' - '9' in the specified path
static void CreateFolders(string path)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", path, a));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", path, a));
        }
    }


public static class Helpers
    {

        // Moves the directory back one step
        public static string DirMoveBack(string path)
        {
            for (int a = path.Length - 1; a > 0; a--)
                if (path[a] == '\\')
                    return path.Substring(0, a);

            return path;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, this is quite messy. If you run the code, it will create the desired folder structure, but I want it done recursively. Im trying to expand my way of thinking, and this seems to be a real brain teaser. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I can make it happen BUT 0-10 makes 11 folders, not 10 :o

Comment: the condition is < 10, so it only creates the 9th folder, or are you talking about recursion? I know iteration might be ideal but i cant seem to get it to work using recursion.. And yeah, you will have to create the folders from 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> (0-> 9), step one back, (0 -> 9), step one back, until you are back at the 9th folder in the root I think? Im just curious as to how it will work :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, recursive is shorter :)  A natural fit for anything that resembles a tree structure:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        CreateFolders(3, "c:\\temp\\temp");
    }

    static void CreateFolders(int depth, string path) {
        if (depth <= 0) return;
        for (int ix = 0; ix <= 10; ++ix) {
            var dir = Path.Combine(path, ix.ToString());
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
            CreateFolders(depth - 1, dir);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah man this is exactly what I wanted. This is great, thanks a lot for the quick input :D

Answer (score 4):

Here is a really simple system that creates 0 -10 folders recursively for `x` levels. Resulting in a structure listed in the picture. The concept is pretty simple, the method calls itself passing in the `path` and `depth` parameters. Where the `path` is the root path the folders should be created at that recursion level and the `depth` is the remaining sub-folders to to create. You will notice on each recursive call the `depth` parameter is reduced by one until it equals zero. At zero the recursion stops.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int maxDepth = 5;
    string initialPath = @"D:\testFolders";
    createFolders(initialPath, maxDepth);
}

static void createFolders(string path, int depth)
{
    depth--;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        string directory = Path.Combine(path, i.ToString());
        if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
        if (depth > 0)
            createFolders(directory, depth);
    }
}
```

[image]